# How to assign function to object property in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have simple use case where i want to validate date input it should be in the format "YYYY/MM/DD" if anything other format passed throw error so question how can i assign function to object property in typescript ?

main.ts

```
const ValidateRuless = [

    {element: "date", values: this.validateDate()}

];

function validateDate(date: string) {
    const date_regex =  /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/ ;
    if (!(date_regex.test(date))) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a function, *don't* use `this.functionName`. Only use `this.` when calling methods of classes.

You probably also want to return a value in both cases in `validateDate`

Example:

```
const ValidateRuless = [

    {element: "date", values: validateDate("2018/05/17")}

];

function validateDate(date: string) {
    const date_regex =  /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/ ;
    if (!(date_regex.test(date))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yyyy/mm/dd this is the correct format but its not taking it always return false

Comment: Debugging your regexp would be a different question